# How to make Glimpse work with production and TeamCity

Tags: glimpse

I have installed Glimpse in my MVC5 EF6 AspNet-solution and have created a custom runtime policy with GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs.
Everything works great when working locally but when I deploy the solution through TeamCity, following error comes up:

> [Csc] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig...
>
> [Csc] GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs(3, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'Glimpse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What can I do to make this work? Manually signing the glimpse DLL-files seems kinda hacky solution and would not like that one.

Comment: are you sure the Glimpse.Core assembly is available? Or the Glimpse NuGet package? Seems like the reference is missing while compiling your solution

Comment: My Csproj-file has "Reference Include"-entries for Glimpse.Ado, Glimpse.AspNet, Glimpse.Core, Glimpse.EF6 and Glimpse.Mvc5 which as far as I know should be enough?

Comment: referencing assemblies from within the project file is only one part of the equation, you also need to make sure they are effectively available at compilation time, which doesn't seem to be the case at first sight